# Automating Azure DevOps Linux Agents

Tags: linux, automation, azure-devops, agent

I am automating the build of my Azure DevOps Linux Agents and I am trying to figure out how I can allow the agent access to other servers.  When building the VM in Azure I supply the public key of my administrative user, but I want to inject the private key somehow without compromising security.  I thought about trying to add a certificate at deploy time and then using that certificate to connect to a Key Vault and pull down the ssh private key.  Any thoughts on other ways to accomplish this?

Comment: AppVeyor has an article on how to save the key to environment and then inject into the actual agent when the build task starts, https://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/private-git-sub-modules/ You can use the same approach on Azure DevOps.

Comment: either key vault or script\dsc extension, cloudinit, perhaps